# Propagation of Uncertainty in Multiple Readings

Tags: statistics

I am trying to calculate the uncertainty of the annual energy consumption for a piece of equipment. I have one full year of hourly power measurements in kW. The power meter has an accuracy of ± 2%.

For simplicity, let's say each of my hourly readings is 100 kW, so that the total annual energy consumption is 876,000 kWh.

I see two possible ways of calculating the uncertainty of the annual energy consumption.

**Option 1**

The uncertainty is equal to the accuracy of the meter, which is ± 2%. Therefore, the uncertainty would be 17,520 kWh.

**Option 2**

The uncertainty is equal to the sum of the uncertainty of each data point. Each data point has an uncertainty of ± 2%, equivalent to 2 kWh. Uncertainty of the total is equal to the sum of squares as per the following:

$$ \sigma_f = \sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2+\sigma_3^2+...\sigma_{8760}^2} $$

This gives a total uncertainty of ± 187 kWh, equivalent to 0.02%.

**Which of these two options is correct? Does anyone have a reference to describe which should be used?**

Comment: The first is termed systematic error because it is (roughly) the same for each data point.  The second is random error because it varies from one point to the next.  Systematic errors do not go away with averaging.  If the meter reads low one time, you might expect it to read low all the time.  Normally you assess the causes of the error and assign them to be one or the other.  You treat the systematic ones as in option 1 and the random ones as in option 2.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would definitely go with 17520 kWh. What value you want to use depends on what is causing the uncertainty.

If the error for each hour were independent from the error for any other hour, then it would be extremely (incredibly extremely) unlikely that all the errors would fall on the same side and be near the maximum value, so you can reasonably expect that the error would be much much smaller. And in fact your variance of the total is the sum of the variances approach works for your particular case.

But for a meter, the major contribution to the error in the reading is almost certainly calibration. That is, it always reads a little low or always reads a little high. This sort of error is additive. With each hour, the total gets farther and farther away from correct. So your 17520 kWh error is much more likely.